# Solving a nonlinear second order ODE numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am struggling to solve the following equation numerically: $x'^2 - xx''=W(t)$, where W(t) is a sinusoidal function, only known by its samples (i.e. no analytic form is known).
Up until now I tried to write it as two first-order ODEs: $\begin{cases}v'=u \\ u'=\displaystyle\frac{u^2-W(t)}{v}\end{cases}$ and find a solution for this system using the ode45 function offered by Matlab, without success. After a few iterations the solution starts to increase towards infinite.
Isn't this the way to solve the above equation?

Regards,
Feri

Comment: Could you show the points which give W(t) ?

Comment: In the simplest case, $W(t) = 1$. Then using the intial conditions $\displaystyle x\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle x'\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$ the solution should be $x(t)=\cos(t)$

Comment: I can't find that $x(t)=cos(t)$ solution that you claim. Also, what's wrong with the solution exploding exponentially if that's the actual behavior of the system. Not all second order systems with sinusoidal forcing oscillate stably.

Comment: $x(t)=\cos(t)$ is indeed a solution: $(-\sin(t))^2-\cos(t)(-\cos(t))=sin^2(t)+cos^2(t)=1$

Answer (score 1):

ode45 would not be the way to go for this type of problem since you're going to have oscillations around zero. These oscillations translate to large eigenvalues in the Jacobian, meaning you will need a highly-A-stable method. You can give ode15s a try, though you may need to use an implicit solver like Implicit Euler or the Midpoint method, solving each time step with Newton's method.

Answer (score 0):

$$x'^2-xx''=-x^2\left(\frac{x'}{x}\right)'$$

Hence we have another system of first order ODE:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x'=xy\\y'=-\frac{W(t)}{x^2}\end{array}\right.$$

Try to find a solution for it.

Comment: I tried this one too, but the ode45 fails to continue after the solution gets around 0. My guess is that the division in the right hand side of the second equation makes the convergence impossible.